# Magento - Multistore implementation

Tags: magento

Im looking at switching to Magento for a project im going to start.

I was wondering if i could get a bit of advice regarding the Multi-Store implementation.

Does this allow seperate admin users for each store?

Would you recommend this implementation for a small hosted ecommerce application?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Warning - as I'm sure you know, don't start a project with Magento unless you are willing to put **a lot** of time into it.

That said, to my knowledge the Multistore setup allows one to run multiple stores with the same administration section. You should be able to create multiple admin users - but restricting them to a store isn't available in normal old community edition. It might be available in one of the pay editions.

That said, this extension may do the trick for you: http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html. Note: I've never personally tried this extension and so cannot vouch for it.

**Edit**

I realized that I never answered your second question.

Though Magento is a very powerful platform with a lot of features, I would not recommend using it for a small hosted ecommerce application. For a small hosted ecommerce store I would consider running [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) with the [WP-E-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) plugin. Wordpress is great for managing website content - and WP-E-Commerce has a lot of features and is consistently being developed and improved upon.

If you are going to go with Magento then I would reccomend using [Nexcess hosting](http://www.nexcess.net/magento-hosting). They specialize in hosting Magento and their Magento plans are already optimized for running Magento websites.

Comment: Thanks for that .... I have been told Magento is a bit rough .... But at the moment, i cant find any decent software ... osCommerce is awesome, but its too old now and not being updated is a bit worrying, Zencart doesnt have enough modules and thats really the same with the majority of them .. To my knowledge Magento is nice up to date looking, alot of modules and regularly updated .... But i do believe its quite slow ... what to do, what to do

Comment: @Chris I agree, there's nothing low maintenance about magento.  It's a strong platform with lots of power, but it will definitely call on your skills and abilities to keep it running well.

Comment: Prestashop is increasingly my "fallback" choice for small webshops. It is modern and actively developed, there is also a growing community of plugin writers.

Answer (score 0):

enterprise (and maybe professional) edition has the feature you are talking about, separating admin users by store. If you need to restrict that in admin level with community edition you can set up multiple software versions from same development branch with different databases (git is awesome on version tool for that). Lots of different ways to do so if Enterprise is out of reach

regarding of performance i guess you will need a powerful VPS or dedicated machine if you are serious about it and as the traffic grows you then should think about load balancing. Look for magento dedicated host companies for that and it won't run in $5 or $20 per month hosts

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> **Does Magento allow seperate admin users
>   for each store?**

The free version (Community version) of Magento doesn't have this feature. There will be a single admin.

But the admin can create user and roles. So, some users can be assigned only to product and category addition page. And some users can only be assigned to Sales part.

**Separate admin for each store**: This feature is present in Enterprise version of Magento but its cost is too high. At present, it **Starts at $12,990 USD/yr**

In my opinion, using or not using Magento depends upon the functionality you are searching for your shop.

If you need lots of features and functionalities for your Shop then go for Magento.

If you just want general functions like displaying product, adding to cart, and checkout (that's all), then you may search for any other open source shopping cart.

You may try [Oscommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/). I have not used it much but I think there is a Oscommerce module for multi admin login for each store.